# Match all files that are inside a folder and ignore one folder inside

Tags: match, glob

I have the following directory structure:

```
root
├─ files
│  ├─ folder1
│  │  ├─ file1.js
│  |  └─ file2.js
│  ├─ folder2
│  │  └─ file3.js
│  ├─ file4.js
|  └─ file5.js
└─ config.js
```

How can I match every file inside of `file` (and subdirectories) except the files that are in `folder1`, in this case `file3.js`, `file4.js` and `file5.js`?
I know I could exclude `folder1` with the following: `files/!(folder1)/*.js`, but this only matches `file3.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `**/files/{*.js,!(folder1)*/*.js}`. You can test using [globster.xyz](https://globster.xyz/?q=**%2Ffiles%2F%7B*.js%2C!(folder1)*%2F*.js%7D&f=%2Froot%2Ffiles%2Ffolder1%2Ffile1.js%2C%2Froot%2Ffiles%2Ffolder1%2Ffile2.js%2C%2Froot%2Ffiles%2Ffolder2%2Ffile3.js%2C%2Froot%2Ffiles%2Ffile4.js%2C%2Froot%2Ffiles%2Ffile5.js%2C%2Froot%2Fconfig.js)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a more elegant way to do this as I am not too familiar with glob, but I think this will get what you are asking for.

```
import glob

exclude_pattern = ['folder1']
file_list = glob.glob('./files/**/*',  recursive=True)

for pattern in exclude_pattern:
    exclude_patternmatch = list(filter(lambda x: pattern in x, file_list))
    for item in exclude_patternmatch:
        file_list.remove(item)

print(file_list)
```

output:

```
['./files/file6.js', './files/file5.js', './files/folder2/file3.js', './files/folder2/file4.js']
```